# Hierarchical Bayesian Modeling

Tags: correlation, hierarchical-bayesian

How does hierarchical bayesian modeling incorporate the correlation present between the observed variables (y1,....,yn)

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide the details of your problem.

Comment: http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/16040/1/16040.pdf

I am currently reading this paper and on page 6 it states that: "The inherent hierarchical nature......"

Is there any proof behind it?
p.s. If your used with working with WinBUGS there's the code attached at the end of the paper

Comment: I recommend http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/ to get a better sense of hierarchical modelling

Answer (score 2):

First, in the Bayesian paradigm, keep in mind that you are building distributions that describe possible values of your parameters of interest (e.g. true mean), and then updating these distributions based on how likely the observed data would be given the underlying parameters.

These distributions are not necessarily independent. They are a joint distribution over all possible combinations of parameter values.

How the different parameters interact depends on how you specify your model. You are more than welcome to create a model in which all the parameters are considered independent. However, in the hierarchical approach, you are creating a specific kind of model in which each of your parameters are themselves drawn from an underlying distribution which has it's own parameter.

If you gave an example of a specific problem which you think should be treated with a hierarchical model, perhaps we could give some specific illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really too general.

just for example, you can suppose $y_1, ... , y_n$ to be distributed as a Multivariate Normal variable where the covariance matrix depends on a vector of parameters $\theta$.
In this way you have incorporated the correlation between observations